# Accessing a .mobileprovision file from code

Tags: macos, cocoa, permissions, provisioning

I'm trying to open a .mobileprovision file from my own MacOS program and read it with

```
[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

The filepath is correct and I'm getting a valid file handle.

When I try to open the file using TextEdit everything works. I can open the file and can read the text inside. It only does not work from code. Then I get a

> "... couldn’t be opened using text encoding Unicode (UTF-8)"

error message. The problem is not the encoding - it's UTF-8. There seems to be a security or permission rule, which doesn't allow to read the file properly.

Does anyone has a solution for this? Maybe I need to add a permission flag with my request, but I can't find anything into this direction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I came accross the same issue with a txt file and solved this by changing NSUTF8StringEncoding to NSUnicodeStringEncoding.

May be your file has been written with different type of encoding. Following are the string encoding available for OSX. Try it.

```
    NSASCIIStringEncoding = 1,      /* 0..127 only */
    NSNEXTSTEPStringEncoding = 2,
    NSJapaneseEUCStringEncoding = 3,
    NSUTF8StringEncoding = 4,
    NSISOLatin1StringEncoding = 5,
    NSSymbolStringEncoding = 6,
    NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding = 7,
    NSShiftJISStringEncoding = 8,          /* kCFStringEncodingDOSJapanese */
    NSISOLatin2StringEncoding = 9,
    NSUnicodeStringEncoding = 10,
    NSWindowsCP1251StringEncoding = 11,    /* Cyrillic; same as AdobeStandardCyrillic */
    NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding = 12,    /* WinLatin1 */
    NSWindowsCP1253StringEncoding = 13,    /* Greek */
    NSWindowsCP1254StringEncoding = 14,    /* Turkish */
    NSWindowsCP1250StringEncoding = 15,    /* WinLatin2 */
    NSISO2022JPStringEncoding = 21,        /* ISO 2022 Japanese encoding for e-mail */
    NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding = 30,

    NSUTF16StringEncoding = NSUnicodeStringEncoding,      /* An alias for NSUnicodeStringEncoding */

    NSUTF16BigEndianStringEncoding = 0x90000100,          /* NSUTF16StringEncoding encoding with explicit endianness specified */
    NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding = 0x94000100,       /* NSUTF16StringEncoding encoding with explicit endianness specified */

    NSUTF32StringEncoding = 0x8c000100,                   
    NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding = 0x98000100,          /* NSUTF32StringEncoding encoding with explicit endianness specified */
    NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding = 0x9c000100        /* NSUTF32StringEncoding encoding with explicit endianness specified */
```